# seeing this error after sitecore installtion ,local setup Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='web_am'], what could be the issue

Tags: content-search, configuration, sql-database, setup

[image]

I am facing issue  on doing local setup for this sitecore, Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='web_am']
not sure why and where exactly this issue is occuring,and what could be the resolution

Comment: hi Anna, I appreciate your effort, unfortunilty this is not helping as i am not able to get into sitecore itself to check throw showconfig

Comment: Looks like you have some CD confifg files in your local installation. You need to review all custom config files in app_config/include folder and find any that reference "web_am". Rename those to have ".disabled" file extension and see if that allows you access to backend.

Comment: I do agree that this question has been asked before and that there are answers to this question posted, albeit maybe not exactly the answers you're looking for. While this question is talking about a different database (web_am) than the question that is already posted, perhaps someone can add a new answer to the original question that can satisfy your issue.